Jest not able to resolve tsconfig extended from node_modules package
I have a monorepo setup using turborepo, I have picked out my tsconfig and made an npm package out of it that can be extended to multiple apps in my monorepo.
{
  "extends": "jc-tsconf/next",
}

It works fine everywhere with my ts files and ts compilation commands and builds but when I have integrated jest for unit test cases in one of my web apps in this mono repo it starts to break.
│   TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
│ error TS6053: File 'jc-tsconf/next' not found.

But as I mentioned I have a monorepo setup and I have my packages and apps in the same repo when I extend using the relative path it starts working.
{
  "extends": "../../packages/jc-tsconf/tsconf.next.json",
}

but I want it to be picked from packages as node_modules, so what can be a way around for this?
